# c# Why delegate\event doesn't get updated after passing it to another class

Tags: c#, events, reference, delegates, invoke

I'm having trouble invoking delegates that were added after I  pass the event to a specific class, I thought that the delegate get updates as objects..

For example this the class that I'm passing the delegate to:

## Updated code (due to some question in the comments)

This is actually +- how I need to run it, Where "ExecutorOnCalculationCompleted" is never invoking (please ignore sleep, and synchronization, I shrink my code to the needed parts)

```
    class Executor
{

    public delegate void CalculationCompletEventHandler(int score);

    public event CalculationCompletEventHandler CalculationCompleted;

    public void Start()
    {
        CalculationCompleted += OnCalculationCompleted;
        Plus plus = new Plus(1, 2, CalculationCompleted);
        Minus minus =  new Minus(5, 2, CalculationCompleted);
        Multi multi =  new Multi(5, 2, CalculationCompleted);
        ...
        ...    They will work async...
    }

    private void OnCalculationCompleted(int score)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCalculationCompleted , score=" + score);
    }
}

class Plus
{
    private Executor.CalculationCompletEventHandler _calculationCompletEventHandler;
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Plus(int a, int b,Executor.CalculationCompletEventHandler calculationCompletEventHandler)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        _calculationCompletEventHandler = calculationCompletEventHandler;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        _calculationCompletEventHandler?.Invoke(a+b);
    }
}



class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Executor executor = new Executor();
        executor.Start(); // async action
        executor.CalculationCompleted += ExecutorOnCalculationCompleted;
        ...
    }

    // This method doesn't get invoked when the class inside Executor fire the event.
    private static void ExecutorOnCalculationCompleted(int score)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExecutorOnCalculationCompleted , score=" + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's because the reference of delegates are not same. `+=` creates a new delegate using Delegate.Combine

Comment: actually the event must be inside `Plus` method, you write same event for `Subtract` etc, the delegate must be in global namespace, don't put it inside a class. `Executor` subscribes its methods to the individual events of Plus and Subtract etc

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What is your goal? For this to work, `Plus` needs to own the event, but then what happens with you add a `Multiply` class?

Comment: Hi @M.kazemAkhgary , I updated my code hope this will clarify some questions

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There currently isn't enough to actually run the code, but you *do* have more than you need.

Comment: @JonSkeet , You are right.. Sorry for that, Done!

Comment: No, that's not a [mcve]. Can I copy/paste/compile/run? No... (`...` isn't valid code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the delegate directly in the constructor. I think you want to put the event into the class. Example:

```
class Plus
{
    public delegate void CalculationCompletEventHandler(int score);
    public event CalculationCompletEventHandler CalculationCompleted;

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Plus(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        if (CalculationCompleted != null)
        {
            CalculationCompleted(a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

you can now use it like that:

```
void Main()
{
    Plus plus = new Plus(1, 2);
    plus.CalculationCompleted += OnCalculationCompleted;
    plus.Calculate();

    plus.CalculationCompleted += OnCalculationCompleted2;
    plus.Calculate();        
}

private void OnCalculationCompleted(int score)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnCalculationCompleted , score=" + score);
}

private void OnCalculationCompleted2(int score)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnCalculationCompleted2 , score=" + score);
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, you maybe only need the event itself if the delegate type is used in different parts of your program.

## After Update in Question

If you want the event in the executor, I would simply pass an action to each of your classes like `Plus`, `Multiply`, ... and invoke the event from the executor:

```
class Executor
{
    public delegate void CalculationCompletEventHandler(int score);
    public event CalculationCompletEventHandler CalculationCompleted;

    public void Start()
    {
        CalculationCompleted += OnCalculationCompleted;
        Plus plus = new Plus(1, 2, FireEvent);        
    }

    private void FireEvent(int score)
    {
        if (CalculationCompleted != null)
        {
            CalculationCompleted(score);
        }
    }

    private void OnCalculationCompleted(int score)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCalculationCompleted , score=" + score);
    }
}

class Plus
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private Action<int> completionAction

    public Plus(int a, int b, Action<int> completionAction)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.completionAction = completionAction;       
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        this.completionAction(a + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right but since this delegate (`CalculationCompletEventHandler`) seems to be shared across multiple classes (as its name suggets) it shouldn't be inside `Plus`, so it can be used for say `Subtract` etc

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ok, then only the event should be inside the `Plus` class

Comment: Hi @Nico , I updated my code hope this will clarify some questions

Comment: Yep!, that will do the trick! invoking the event from the parent class. 
Thanks!